How are heterosexual male and female sexual attraction different?
It would appear that heterosexual men are definitely attracted to the physical attractiveness of women as the primary factor yet it is really unclear how women feel. Many women say they care about looks as much as men but somehow they also really care about status and sense of humor and job security of men in question.  Yet there are tons of women that want “hot” guys so it’s unclear what they are really attracted to. Many women also find men who look at them as creepy yet men want nothing more than women to look at them. On a physiological level-how does sexual attraction truly differ for men and women?
